# How to prevent CPU resources from being redirected when browser tab loses focus?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

In Firefox or Chrome, how can I **prevent** a tab's assigned CPU resources from being redirected when I switch to a different tab? I want it to continue 100% exactly as if I was still directly focused on that tab, even though I am not.

I do not care how to do this, whether it's tweaking about:preferences or installing an extension. I would like to know any and all ways this is possible, in current versions of both browsers (including if necessary development versions, nightly builds, etc).

Comment: I don't think you will find that you can assert any control on this. The specific threading model the software employs will be baked into the code at a low level, so it can't be altered/replaced by plugins, and there generally isn't a lot of configuration exposed. On top of that, the OS is responsible for what threads get time on the CPU, and an application can only do so much to stack the deck.

Comment: I thought it was worth a shot given there is a lot of advice and methods for how to do the opposite (eg Tab Memory Purge - Chrome extension). Seems not too far fetched that there could be something that would trick the browser into thinking the tab is still focused, but perhaps it is unlikely, since it's the opposite issue of what people are usually trying to solve.